# How to get QLineEdit's value, which is not at ui?

Tags: qt

How to get QLineEdit's value, which is not at ui?

```
QLineEdit* le_year = new QLineEdit(this);
QLineEdit* le_month = new QLineEdit(this);
QLineEdit* le_day = new QLineEdit(this);

int year = le_year->text().toInt();
int month = le_year->text().toInt();
int day = le_year->text().toInt();
```

Comment: what do you mean? you're getting it!

Comment: What do you mean by "not at ui"?

Comment: how come you create a QLineEdit which do not want to show on UI?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WQrqLVG9
here is the code, the lineedits arent created from ui->

Answer (score 0):

In your sample you query the edit boxes with `le_year->text().toInt()` in the window constructor, i.e. when the user hasn't yet had a chance to enter the data. So, obviously, the right way to do it is to query the data when it's available, for instance, when the user presses 'OK':

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QLabel* information = new QLabel("Please enter your birthday",this);

    QLabel* label_year = new QLabel("Year",this);
    QLabel* label_month = new QLabel("Month",this);
    QLabel* label_day = new QLabel("Day", this);

    QLineEdit* le_year = new QLineEdit(this);
    QLineEdit* le_month = new QLineEdit(this);
    QLineEdit* le_day = new QLineEdit(this);

    QPushButton* pb_okay = new QPushButton("OK",this);

    QGridLayout *gl_example = new QGridLayout(centralWidget());

    gl_example->addWidget(information, 0, 0);
    gl_example->addWidget(label_year, 1, 0);
    gl_example->addWidget(label_month, 1, 1);
    gl_example->addWidget(label_day, 1, 2);

    gl_example->addWidget(le_year, 2, 0);
    gl_example->addWidget(le_month, 2, 1);
    gl_example->addWidget(le_day,2,2);

    gl_example->addWidget(pb_okay,3,0,1,3);

    connect(pb_okay, &QPushButton::clicked,
            [this, le_year, le_month, le_day]()
    {
      QDate birthday {le_year->text().toInt(),
            le_month->text().toInt(),
            le_day->text().toInt()};

      QMessageBox::information(this, "Information",
                               "Your age: " + birthday.toString(Qt::ISODate),
                               QMessageBox::Ok);
    });
}
```